# Why can I retrieve environment variable in one part of my code, but not another?

Tags: django, environment-variables, django-wsgi

I've stored an API token as an environment variable in my wsgi file. I'm able to retrieve it in one instance in my Django app, but not another.

I'm able to use the token successfully during a save_model operation in my admin. When I use nearly identical code in a management command I get an auth error.

My wsgi.py file:

```
import os    
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'] = '12344567890qazxswedcvfrtgbnhyujmkiolp'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Working admin.py usage:

```
import os
from slacker import Slacker

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
            if obj.condition == True:
                super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
                token = os.getenv('SLACK_TOKEN')
                slack = Slacker(token)
                slack.chat.post_message('#test-channel', 'mymessage')
```

Not working management command usage:

```
import os
from slacker import Slacker

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            #test condition
        except:
            token = os.getenv('SLACK_TOKEN')
            slack = Slacker(token)
            slack.chat.post_message('#newsflow-test', 'mymessage')
```

Troubleshooting indicates the env variable isn't loading -- print(token) produces None response when I run the management command or try to retrieve the token in the Django shell.

Answer (score 1):

wsgi.py is imported by your Python application server, e.g. gunicorn. Management commands are executed directly and bypass importing wsgi.py. You should use some mechanism, e.g. django-dotenv to load environment variables from a `.env` file both in your manage.py script and wsgi.py application initializer.